# is it possible to integrate in my ready checkout paypal code to add monthly payment function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, paypal, paypal-subscriptions

*is it possible to integrate in my ready checkout paypal code to add monthly payment function?
I have developed a function that is responsible for receiving a one-time payment, but I need to add a function that will be responsible for charging a monthly fixed amount from a person who wants to make a monetary contribution
*

```
import React, { useEffect } from "react";
import {
  PayPalScriptProvider,
  PayPalButtons,
  usePayPalScriptReducer,
} from "@paypal/react-paypal-js";

import imgLogo from "../../../images/FUMlogo.png";
import imgColageDesk from "../../../images/Donate/colageDesk.png";
import DonateBTN from "../../UI/Button/DonateBTN/DonateBTN";
import DonateOther from "../../UI/Button/DonateBTN/DonateOther";
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from "react-redux";
import {
  setAmountMoney,
  setFlowAmountMoney,
} from "../../../Store/Reducers/inputMoneyAmount";
export default function Donate() {
  const amountDonate = useSelector((state) => state.inputMoneyAmount.amount);
  const flowAmountDonate = useSelector(
    (state) => state.inputMoneyAmount.flowAmount
  );
  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  const amount50 = () => {
    dispatch(setFlowAmountMoney(false));
    dispatch(setAmountMoney(50));
  };

  const amount100 = () => {
    dispatch(setFlowAmountMoney(false));
    dispatch(setAmountMoney(100));
  };
  const amount200 = () => {
    dispatch(setFlowAmountMoney(false));
    dispatch(setAmountMoney(200));
  };

  // This values are the props in the UI
  const amount = amountDonate ? amountDonate : flowAmountDonate + "";
  const currency = "USD";
  const style = { layout: "vertical", color: "blue" };

  // Custom component to wrap the PayPalButtons and handle currency changes
  const ButtonWrapper = ({ currency, showSpinner }) => {
    // usePayPalScriptReducer can be use only inside children of PayPalScriptProviders
    // This is the main reason to wrap the PayPalButtons in a new component
    const [{ options, isPending }, dispatch] = usePayPalScriptReducer();

    useEffect(() => {
      dispatch({
        type: "resetOptions",
        value: {
          ...options,
          currency: currency,
        },
      });
    }, [currency, showSpinner]);

    return (
      <>
        {showSpinner && isPending && <div className="spinner" />}
        <PayPalButtons
          style={style}
          disabled={false}
          forceReRender={[amount, currency, style]}
          fundingSource={undefined}
          createOrder={(data, actions) => {
            return actions.order
              .create({
                purchase_units: [
                  {
                    amount: {
                      currency_code: currency,
                      value: amount,
                    },
                  },
                ],
              })
              .then((orderId) => {
                // Your code here after create the order
                return orderId;
              });
          }}
          onApprove={function (data, actions) {
            return actions.order.capture().then(function () {
              // Your code here after capture the order
            });
          }}
        />
      </>
    );
  };
  // bg-[#010321]
  return (
    <main className="flex flex-col items-center  w-full h-screen sm:h-auto text-white   bg-[#1b1d33] pt-[8vh] sm:pt-[9vw] lg:pt-[7vw] xl:pt-[5vw] relative ">
      <section className=" flex flex-col items-center justify-center px-[3vw] ">
        <img
          className=" w-full sm:w-[70vw] md:w-[60vw] lg:w-[40vw] xl:w-[30vw]"
          src={imgColageDesk}
          alt="colage"
        />
        <img
          className="w-[10vw] lg:w-[8vw] xl:w-[5vw] h-[10vw] lg:h-[8vw] xl:h-[5vw] mt-10"
          src={imgLogo}
          alt="logo"
        />
        <h3 className="text-xs sm:text-sm md:text-base lg:text-lg mt-5">
          Donate to
        </h3>
        <h1 className="uppercase mt-3 text-sm sm:text-base md:text-lg lg:text-xl font-bold ">
          forward ukraine ministries
        </h1>
        <p className="w-full sm:w-[70vw] md:w-[60vw] lg:w-[40vw] xl:w-[30vw] text-center text-xs sm:text-sm md:text-base lg:text-lg mt-2">
          A humanitarian catastrophe is unfolding in Ukraine as attacks of war
          put millions of lives at risk. Support Military & Refugee
        </p>
        <div className="w-[80vw] sm:w-[50vw] md:w-[30vw] flex justify-around mt-14 mb-4 sm:mt-15 text-black">
          <DonateBTN setAmount={amount50} amount="$50" />

          <DonateBTN setAmount={amount100} amount="$100" />
          <DonateBTN setAmount={amount200} amount="$200" />
          <DonateOther name="Other" />
        </div>
        <input
          value={flowAmountDonate}
          onChange={(e) => dispatch(setFlowAmountMoney(e.target.value))}
          onKeyDown={(e) =>
            ["ArrowUp", "ArrowDown", "e", "E", "+", "-", ".", ","].includes(
              e.key
            ) && e.preventDefault()
          }
          className={`${
            flowAmountDonate
              ? "block font-bold w-[80%] sm:w-3/4 md:w-[85%] h-[7vw] sm:h-[6vw] md:h-[4vw]  mb-4 sm:mb-8 text-black rounded-lg  bg-gradient-to-r from-blue-500 to-yellow-500  focus:from-pink-500 focus:to-yellow-500  hover:from-pink-500 hover:to-yellow-500"
              : "hidden"
          }`}
          type="number"
          name=""
        />

        <PayPalScriptProvider
          options={{
            "client-id": "test",
            components: "buttons",
            currency: "USD",
          }}
        >
          <ButtonWrapper currency={currency} showSpinner={false} />
        </PayPalScriptProvider>
      </section>
    </main>
  );
}
```

Comment: i need some checkbox item(toggle) to provide subscription ( true or false)

Answer (score 0):

Recurring payments use a separate process.

For react-paypal-js in particular you can see an example of a Subscription checkout [here](https://paypal.github.io/react-paypal-js/?path=/docs/example-subscriptions--default). You can create subscription plans in your live PayPal account [here](https://www.paypal.com/billing/plans) (or for a sandbox business account [here](https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/billing/plans), or via API [here](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/subscriptions/v1/#plans_create)). The client-id that a subscription plan is created for ***must*** correspond to the client-id that the JS SDK is loaded with for checkout. If it does not correspond, the error will be RESOURCE_NOT_FOUND.